# Mockito - Argument Captor not capturing and no interactions

Tags: java, junit, mockito, error-logging

I'm working on some old code that does not handle exceptions very well.  One test I'm writing, stubs a method that throws an exception, which I need to confirm is the correct exception.  The only way to test this exception that I can see, is to capture the argument when it is being logged and compare the strings.

When I run this I get:

Wanted but not invoked: logger.error(Capturing argument)

Actually there were zero interactions with this mock

```
@Test
public void testRunCipherThrowsException() throws Exception
{
    final Logger logger = mock(Logger.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<Logger> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Logger.class);

    when(cipher.doSomething(any(byte[].class))).thenThrow(new IllegalBlockSizeException("Bad block size"));
    Mockito.verify(logger).error(argument.capture());

    _task.run();

    assertEquals("The execution failed.  Details: Bad block size", argument.getValue().getName());
}
```

Here is a snippet from the class I am testing - in debug I am hitting that line of code every time.

```
try
{

final byte[] result = cipher.doSomething(testData);

catch (final Exception ex)
    {
        _consequtiveFailures++;
        _logger.error("The execution failed.  Details: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
```

I've tried to arrange the test a few different ways thinking the verify might not be getting setup correctly.  I have also tried a few different ways of setting of the mock Logger object.  It is my first time using argument captor, so hopefully I'm just missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> final Logger logger = mock(Logger.class);

This is a logger instance you have created locally for your test method; it will therefore not be used by the class you are testing. You need to at least `spy()` the actual logger instance.

What is more, you `verify()` *after* you execute (I guess here that `_task.run()` executes the code which will trigger the exception); which means that even if you spied on the correct `Logger` instance, at the time you `verify()` it, there will be nothing.

So:

- actually mock, or spy, the actual logger used by `_task`;
- verify mock/spy interactions (`Mockito.verify()` works for both) *after* you have executed the method.

Comment: The big problem was the logger.. once I got that going, the rest fell into place.  Thank you.